# How to get the url of a page inside iframe?

Tags: php, iframe, tracking

I wonder if I could learn the url inside iframe even if user clicks another link. To clarify; imagine that I have iframed stackoverflow.com and you visited that page. Then you decided to click Ask Question button while you are still inside iframe. Could I track your steps?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. The [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_Origin_Policy) prevents any and all access to the iframe, so you can't attach any listeners to the iframed document.

Plus in the specific instance of Stack Overflow, the site has a Frame buster mechanism and won't allow to be embedded in an iframe.

Comment: Thanks Pekka. That's too bad.

Comment: You would have to proxy the iframe content, which means rewriting all links in the proxied content. Not impossible to do be requires server-side scripting.

Comment: @Capsule yeah, but that will break most sites nowadays: JavaScript won't work any more, Ajax calls will go wrong....

Comment: yeah, probably impossible to handle if any URL can be loaded in the iframe bu manageable with a restricted set of pages (which is probably the case when using iframes)

Answer (score -1):

you can get the initial URL of the frame though

```
document.getElementById('elementid').src
```

Comment: Nope. This will fetch the initial `src` property of the iframe only. The property will not change if the iframe changes its location.